# Get immediate folder of file using find (issue with spaces)

Tags: bash, find, freebsd

I'm trying to search my Movies folder to find the immediate folder of the .MKV file I'm searching for. The below works (echo 5) to save the immediate folder as a variable, BUT, it does not work if $mkvfile contains spaces. I've been unsuccessful in getting $moviename to work if $mkvfile contains spaces.

```
searchdir="/mnt/storagepool/storage/downloads"
moviedir="/mnt/storagepool/storage/media/Movies"

#MKVs in root folder

for filename in $searchdir/*.mkv; do
  #Get .MKV file from root of the downloads/search directory.
    mkvfile="$(basename $filename)"
    #echo 2 $mkvfile

  #Search for the MKV file in the media/Movies directory to find the corresponding movie folder name
    #echo 3 "${moviedir}"
    #echo 4 $mkvfile
    moviename=$(find "${moviedir}" -name '$moviedir' -prune -o -name "$mkvfile" -exec dirname {} \;)
    echo 5 "${moviename}"
done
```

Comment: Double quote `$filename`: `mkvfile="$(basename "$filename")"`

Comment: @guillermochamorro - That was it! Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: Also note that `$moviedir` in `-name '$moviedir'` will not be expanded due to the single quotes.

Comment: They're called "directories" in Unix and BSD, not "folders" which is a Windows-ism for non-professionals. A folder is not the same as a directory.